# Getting a list of available hierarchies from statistics.gov.scot

Tags: sparql, opendata

I'm interested in obtaining a list of available distinct hierarchies from [statistics.gov.scot](http://statistics.gov.scot/). The best-fit hierarchies, which I would like to list, are as follow:

```
http://statistics.gov.scot/def/hierarchy/best-fit#community-health-partnership
http://statistics.gov.scot/def/hierarchy/best-fit#council-area
http://statistics.gov.scot/def/hierarchy/best-fit#country
```

As available through **API** section of [this sample geography](http://statistics.gov.scot/doc/statistical-geography/S01000001).

## Desired results

I would like for the desired results to return:

```
community-health-partnership
council-area
country
```

How can I construct query that would actually produce that, I can get a list of available all geographies via:

```
PREFIX sdmx: <http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx/2009/dimension#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?framework 
WHERE {
    ?a sdmx:refArea ?framework .
} LIMIT 10
```

I was trying something on the lines:

```
PREFIX fits: <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/hierarchy/best-fit#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?framework 
WHERE {
    ?a fits ?framework .
} LIMIT 10
```

but naturally this syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting on [their SPARQL endpoint](http://statistics.gov.scot/sparql), you could do something like this --

```
DESCRIBE <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/hierarchy/best-fit#country>
```

Then, based on those results, you might try something like this, which results aren't exactly what you say you want, but might be better --

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT  ?hierarchy
        ?label
WHERE
  { ?hierarchy  rdfs:subPropertyOf  <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/hierarchy/best-fit>
             ;  rdfs:label          ?label
  }
```

Comment: how can I get  object B's data property if that object B is linked to object A via some object property.  Like in my case Automobile and Registration are two classes and automobile has hasRegistration object property. Registration has data property registration_number. So I want to get registration_number value along with data properties of Automobile? Thanks

Comment: @MohsinSaeed - That's what we call "a new question." Please [pose it as such, in conformance with site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).